# Cannot login website with httprequest POST in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to write a bit of code to login to a website. But it's not working. Please can you give me some advice. This is my a bit of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://pagehype.com/login.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = 10000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729) (Prevx 3.0.5)";
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "username=user&password=password&processlogin=1&return=";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string htmldoc = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        Console.Write(htmldoc);
    }
```

Many thanks,

Comment: well, are you sure that is the way username and password are sent (i.e. you know its not sent via a HTTP-Authenticate header)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP logins use `PHPSESSID` cookie. You'll need to capture this and pass it back in the CookieContainer. This is how the server will recognise you as an authenticated user.

The cookie is set in the Set-Cookie header in the initial response. You'll need to parse it to recreate the cookie in your container (don't forget the path (and domain?)

```
var setCookie = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
response.Close();

container = new CookieContainer();
foreach (var cookie in setCookie.Split(','))
{
    var split = cookie.Split(';');
    string name = split[0].Split('=')[0];
    string value = split[0].Split('=')[1];
    var c = new Cookie(name, value);

    if (cookie.Contains(" Domain="))
        c.Domain = split.Where(x => x.StartsWith(" Domain")).First().Split('=')[1];
    else
    {
        c.Domain = ".pagehype.com";
    }

    if (cookie.Contains(" Path="))
        c.Path = split.Where(x => x.StartsWith(" Path")).First().Split('=')[1];

    container.Add(c);
}
```

Then add this container to your request.

Comment: @KoMenXe.Are you sure you are looking at the Response from Fiddler? Having just created an account and logged in, I can see that the process also returns `mnm_user` and `mnm_key` cookies. You need to parse these (definitely the `mnm_key` at the least) and use them in further requests to impersonate the authenticated user.

Comment: This code works great, except if your cookie has an expiration date in the format "expires=Thu, 05-Apr-2012 14:11:33 GMT;" because the string splits breaks after the "Thu".  I dumped them with this code: Regex regExpires = new Regex("expires=.*;"); setCookie = regExpires.Replace(setCookie, "");

Answer (score 2):

Use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  to view the http request sent went you login in using a browser and ensure that the request you build in code is the same.